# custom indexing for arrays in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, for-loop, memory-efficient

I questioned this myself after noticing this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260156/how-do-i-create-dynamic-variable-names-inside-a-loop).

```
for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; ++i) {
    this["marker"+i] = "some stuff";
}
```

- this is an array of strings with indexes "marker"+i.

how does interpreter handle such array naming? any consequences, such as waste of memory, etc?

Comment: That question is about Javascript. You're now asking something about C#, but it's not clear what... in particular, that just won't work with an *array*... it would work with a type using a custom indexer, but it's still not clear what you're asking about, especially in terms of an "interpreter".

Comment: And you know the question you linked is from Javascript ? and it is a bad idea ?

Comment: Are you looking for `Dictionary<string,string>`?

Answer (score 2):

The question you referenced was in javascript, and C# is a completely different beast.

In C#, the index must be an integer, as it is a reference to the position in the array. If you want to use something like `"marker" + i` as your access point to the data, then you'll need to use a key value pair data type similar to Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<String, String> myDict = new Dictionary<String, String>();
for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; ++i) 
{
    myDict.Add("marker"+i, "some stuff");
}
```