# Create multiple variables inside for loop

Tags: javascript, variables, for-loop

I am trying to create multiple new variables inside a loop.
The number of new variables depends on the lenght of another variable (variable "list" used below).

```
for(var i = 0; i < list.lenght; i++) 
{ 
var counter + i;   // create new variable (i.e. counter1, counter2,...)
}
```

I found a lot of very simmilar questions on StackOverflow, and the answer is mostly using an array (i.e. [How do I create dynamic variable names inside a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260156/how-do-i-create-dynamic-variable-names-inside-a-loop)).

If I use the suggested solution, do I create an array of variables? So in my case I will create multiple counters and I can then add values to that variables, i.e.:

```
counter6++;
```

If that is not the case how could I tackle the problem?

I apologize for asking you to explain an old answer, but I cannot comment in the old one because of low reputation.

Comment: That upvote sorts your 50 rep ;)

Comment: Should the dynamically created variable be assigned a value?

Comment: what would you do with the new created variables? how would you address them?

Comment: counter + i is not  correct syntax

Comment: for what are you need the variable for ?

Comment: You don't create an "array of variables". You create an array of values, exactly as shown in the answers in the dupe.

Comment: The variables would be counters (intiger). At first I only want to declare them. Later on I would just use "counter++;" on them.

Comment: @user2375263: yep, and instead of `counter6++` you'll write `counter[6]++`

Comment: @georg Note, variable identifiers can be created from an object.

Comment: Thank you very much georg (and everybody else). That helps a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some options here :

Create them global (not best practice ) :

```
for(var i = 0; i < list.lenght; i++){ 
  window['counter' + i] = 0;   // create counter1, counter2,...)
}
```

Use object :

```
var scope = {};
for(var i = 0; i < list.lenght; i++){ 
  scope['counter' + i] = 0;   // create scope.counter1, scope.counter2,...)
}
```

Use Object with `with` keyword

```
var scope = {};
for(var i = 0; i < list.lenght; i++){ 
  scope['counter' + i] = 0;   // create scope.counter1, scope.counter2,...)
}
with(scope){
 // here you can acesess keys in the scope object like them variable on the function scope
 counter0++
}
```

Use plain old Array

```
var scope = new Array(list.length);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create an object, set property names to expected variable names, then use object destructuring assignment to get the property assignment or index of an object having a `.length` as a variable identifier; or use array destructuring to assign an identifier to a specfic index.

```js
let [list, obj] = ["abc", {}];

for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  obj["counter" + i] = list[i]
}

let {counter0, counter1, counter2} = obj;

console.log(counter0, counter1, counter2);
```

Alternatively

```js
let list  = "abc";

let {0:counter0, 1:counter1, 2:counter2} = list;

console.log(counter0, counter1, counter2);
```

```js
let list  = ["a","b","c"];

let [counter0, counter1, counter2] = list;

console.log(counter0, counter1, counter2);
```