# How do we initialise multiple variables using for loop?

Tags: javascript

```
let arr=["a","b","c"]
for (let i=0;i<3;i++){
let arr[i]=i
}
```

//Result is expected to be be let a=1 ; let b=1; let c=1;

//Why isnt this working and how do we initialise multiple variables using for loop to get a=1;b=1;c=1 ?

Your help will be appreciated

Comment: Get rid of the `let` inside the loop; it's a syntax error. The array is already declared.

Comment: I realized the first part of the question, "Why isn't this working?", is not answered in the dupe. But the answer is simply, because it's invalid syntax according to the language specification.

Comment: I don't think it's not a duplicate of the flagged question. But it is a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42739390/10079978 check this hope this will work for u