# Jmeter. How to refer to indexed variables in the loops by name

Tags: javascript, variables, groovy, jmeter

I have declared a range of indexed JMeter variables d1..dn.

Is there a way to operate with it within JS or Groovy script loop?

For instance I want to print all those variable, but I have problem with referring to them by name

```
for (i = 1; i<n; i++)
{
log.info(?)
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to do this. What you are trying to do - while completely doable - is generally discouraged and (in most cases) can be done better in other ways. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8260202/2649853) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260156/how-do-i-create-dynamic-variable-names-inside-a-loop/8260188?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) for an approach you can use - Some other answers there suggest other methods (using arrays, for example) which may serve you better

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create dynamic variable names inside a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260156/how-do-i-create-dynamic-variable-names-inside-a-loop)

Comment: @ChiragRavindra the question is about JMeter variables

Comment: @user7294900 I'm sorry. I might have misunderstood. I was going by this `Is there a way to operate with it within JS or Groovy script loop`. Which asks specifically about JS and the question has been tagged as javascript :) That being said, I still feel the question marked as a possible duplicate (and specifically, the answer marked in my comment) answers the question OP is asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JMeter you should just concatenate i using  [vars.get](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#get-java.lang.String-):

```
for (i = 1; i<n; i++)
{
    log.info(vars.get("d" + i) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1.upto(n,{
    log.info(vars.get('d' + it))
})
```

Demo:

[image: Groovy Iterate Variables]

More information:

- [Groovy Range Operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_range_operator)
- [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) - this is exposed to JSR223 Test Elements as `vars` shorthand
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)