# How can I create dynamic objects with unique variable names inside a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, audio

I'm trying to create 4 different audio objects in JS in a programmatic way. I have seen similar threads to this like in this thread: ["How do I create dynamic variable names inside a loop?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260156/how-do-i-create-dynamic-variable-names-inside-a-loop)

However, the change in variable name capitalises on the looping stage. Inside the thread there are also answers using the `this` keyword, though I am unsure how to use that programmatically in a loop.

Attempt:

```
var buttonColours = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"]
var sounds = [];

for (var i=0; i < buttonColours.length; i++) {
  sounds[i] = new Audio(`sounds/${buttonColours[i]}.mp3`); // Eg. name of audio file - 'blue.mp3'
}

console.log(sounds);
```

Current Output:

```
 [audio, audio, audio, audio]
```

Desired Output *(each storing a different Audio object as they play different sounds)*:

```
 [redSound, blueSound, greenSound, yellowSound]
```

Comment: Why not simply use an object where you can name the keys?

Comment: the log is just saying they are `audio` objects. I'm not sure the structure of said object but if you look for it's path property I bet it's `sounds/red.mp3` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the audio objects in an array use an object instead. And to put them in use you can loop over the keys of the object using Object.keys(sounds)

```
var buttonColours = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"]
var sounds = {};

for (var i=0; i < buttonColours.length; i++) {
  sounds[buttonColours[i]+"Sound"] = new Audio(`sounds/${buttonColours[i]}.mp3`); // Eg. name of audio file - 'blue.mp3'
}

console.log(sounds);
//{redSound: audio, blueSound: audio, greenSound: audio, yellowSound: audio}
```